An integral containing modified Bessel functions
During my studies I am facing the following problem. Let $I_\nu(x)$ be the modified Bessel function for $\nu\in(0,1/2]$.
I want to compute the following integral (it is are resolvent)
$$
R(z) = \frac{1}{\nu^\nu\Gamma(\nu-1)}\frac{1}{z}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{q'_\nu(x)}{q_\nu(x)q_\nu\left((1-z^{-1})^{\nu}x\right)}dx
$$
where
$$
q_\nu(x) = \sqrt{x}[I_\nu(2\nu x^{\frac{1}{2\nu}})+I_{-\nu}(2\nu x^{\frac{1}{2\nu}})]
$$
Note that this function satisfies the ODE
$$
q''_\nu(x) = x^{\alpha}q_\nu(x) \quad , \quad \nu = \frac{1}{\alpha + 2}
$$
I thought a change of variables might be a good idea so I put $2\nu x^{\frac{1}{2\nu}}=x'$
and get (renaming $x'\to x$)
$$
R(z) = \frac{2^{\nu}}{\Gamma(\nu-1)z}\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{g'_\nu(x)}{g_\nu(x)g_\nu\left((1-z^{-1})^{\frac{1}{2}}x\right)}dx
$$
where $z\in\mathbb{C}$ is a complex number and
$$
g_\nu(x) = x^\nu[I_\nu(x) + I_{-\nu}(x)]\quad .
$$
Eventually what I am interested in is
$$
f(y) = \frac{1}{\pi}\lim_{\epsilon\to 0^+}\Im \, R(y-i \epsilon)
$$
where $\Im$ is the imaginary part. My wanna be strategy is to use residues theorem. When analytically continued to the complex plane, the integrand has poles at locations $w_n$ and $w_n(1-z^{-1})^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ where $w_n$ are the complex zeros of $g(w)$ i.e. $g(w_n) = 0$. These are also the zeros of $I_\nu(w) + I_{-\nu} (w)$ and they are not too difficult to compute numerically. Apparently none of them is real (except $w=0$ of course). Also, using the series representation of the modified Bessel function
$$
I_\nu(x) = \sum_{k\geq 0}\frac{\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2k+\nu}}{k!\Gamma(k+\nu+1)}
$$
one can see that it is possible to write
$$
g_\nu(x) = x^{2\nu}r_1(x) + r_2(x)
$$
where $r_1$ and $r_2$ are entire functions of their arguments being power series. Thus $g_\nu(x)$ has a branch point singularity at $x=0$. The cut might be chosen in a smart way to make residues theorem applicable and sum over all singularities.
I would also be interested in a numerically stable method to compute $f(y)$. If one evaluates the limit defining $f$ first it is possible to get another integral of almost the same structure as $R$ but standard Bessel functions $J_\nu(x)$ will appear and these oscillates wildly making numerical integration very hard.
Expanding $R(z)$ around $z=+\infty$ gives access to all the moments of $f(y)$ but giving an analytic expression for the is pretty complicated.
I will look forward an advice from experts in complex analysis for the resolution of this problem. Thank you all.
This question also appears here.

Long comment. This answer is not intended to give a full answer. Instead, I would like to share some observations:
1. Since $(1-y^{-1})^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is real for $y \in \mathbb{R} \setminus [0, 1]$, we find that $f(y) = 0$ for such $y$'s.
2. For $y \in (0, 1]$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, we have
$$ (1-(y-i\varepsilon)^{-1})^{\frac{1}{2}} = \left( \frac{-y(1-y) + \varepsilon^2 - i\varepsilon}{y^2+\varepsilon^2} \right)^{\frac{1}{2}} \in \text{fourth quadrant}. $$
In particular, this converges to $-i (y^{-1} - 1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ as $\varepsilon \to 0^+$. Now, a numerical computation suggests that $g_{\nu}(z)$ has no zeros in the right-half plane $\operatorname{Re}(z) \geq 0$. Assuming this is true, we can expect that
$$ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{g'_{\nu}(x)}{g_{\nu}(x)g_{\nu}((1-z^{-1})^{1/2} x)} \, \mathrm{d}x
\to \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{g'_{\nu}(x)}{g_{\nu}(x)g_{\nu}(-i\xi x)} \, \mathrm{d}x $$
where $\xi = (y^{-1} - 1)^{\frac{1}{2}}$. (Whether interchanging the limit and integral is justified or not depends on the asymptotic behavior of $g_{\nu}$ near its imaginary axis, which I don't have any idea.)
3. For each small $\delta$ and with $\left| \arg z \right| < \frac{\pi}{2} - \delta$, we know that
$$ \frac{g'_{\nu}(z)}{g_{\nu}(z)}
= \frac{z g_{\nu-1}(z)}{g_{\nu}(z)}
\sim 1
\qquad \text{and}\qquad
g_{\nu}(z)
\sim \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}} z^{\nu-\frac{1}{2}} e^z
$$
as $z \to \infty$. Now, for each fixed $y \in (0, 1]$ and small $\varepsilon > 0$, recall that $(1-z^{-1})^{1/2}$ with $z = y - i\epsilon$ lies in the fourth quadrant, hence in the wedge $\left| \arg z \right| < \frac{\pi}{2} - \delta$ if $\delta$ is also small. So by the above asymptotic behavior, we may "rotate" the contour (or consider an appropriate wedge contour and letting the radius go to $\infty$). This results in
\begin{align*}
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{g'_{\nu}(x)}{g_{\nu}(x)g_{\nu}((1-z^{-1})^{1/2} x)} \, \mathrm{d}x
&= \int_{0}^{\omega \infty} \frac{g'_{\nu}(x)}{g_{\nu}(x)g_{\nu}((1-z^{-1})^{1/2} x)} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&\to \int_{0}^{\omega \infty} \frac{g'_{\nu}(x)}{g_{\nu}(x)g_{\nu}(-i\xi x)} \, \mathrm{d}x  \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\omega g'_{\nu}(\omega x)}{g_{\nu}(\omega x)g_{\nu}(-i\xi \omega x)} \, \mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
where $\omega$ satisfies $|\omega| = 1$ and $0 < \arg \omega < \frac{\pi}{2}$. Due to the exponential growth of $g_{\nu}(-i\xi \omega x)$, the last integral is numerically more stable than the one without $\omega$. The figure below computes
$$ y \quad \mapsto \quad 
\operatorname{Im}\left[ \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\omega g'_{\nu}(\omega x)}{g_{\nu}(\omega x)g_{\nu}(-i(y^{-1}-1)^{1/2} \omega x)} \, \mathrm{d}x \right] $$
as a function of $y$ for $\omega = e^{i\pi/4}$ and for $\alpha = 1, 5, 25$:src)


(Added)
4. Let
$$ a_{\nu}(z) = \operatorname{Im} \int_{0}^{z} \frac{g'_{\nu}(w)}{g_{\nu}(w)} \, \mathrm{d}w $$
denote the argument of $g_{\nu}(z)$, where the integral is taken along any path from $0$ to $z$ lying in the right half-plane. Then Hankel's expansion tells that $\sqrt{z}J_{\nu}(z)$, for $z$ large, behaves almost like a sine function with phase shifted. Consequently, we anticipate that

large zeros of $g_{\nu}(x)$ are spaced almost by $2\pi i$, and consequently,

the average argument change of $g_{\nu}(x)$ in the positive imaginary direction is $1$, or equivalently, $a_{\nu}(ix) \approx x$ for large $x > 0$.


Although I don't have any formal proof of this, a numerical computation conforms to this claim:src_

Now let $h(y)$ denote the imaginary part of the integral (without the prefactor). Then by integration by parts,
\begin{align*}
h(y)
&= \operatorname{Im} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{g'_{\nu}(x)}{g_{\nu}(x)g_{\nu}(-i\xi x)} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \operatorname{Im} \int_{0}^{i \infty} \frac{g'_{\nu}(x)}{g_{\nu}(x)g_{\nu}(-i\xi x)} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \operatorname{Im} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{i g'_{\nu}(ix)}{g_{\nu}(ix)g_{\nu}(\xi x)} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{a_{\nu}(i x / \xi) g_{\nu}'(x)}{g_{\nu}(x)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x
\end{align*}
So, if $y \to 1^-$, then $\xi = \sqrt{y^{-1} - 1} \to 0^+ $, and so, $\xi^{-1} \to \infty$. Assuming our ansatz on the average behavior of $a_{\nu}$, it follows that
$$ h(y)
\sim \frac{1}{\xi} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x g_{\nu}'(x)}{g_{\nu}(x)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x
\sim \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-y}} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{g_{\nu}(x)}, \quad \text{as } y \to 1^-. $$
On the other hand, as $z \to 0$, we have
$$ a_{\nu}(z) \sim \operatorname{Im}\left[ \frac{\Gamma(1-\nu)}{4^{\nu}\Gamma(1+\nu)} z^{2\nu} \right]. $$
Hence, as $y \to 0^+$, we have $\xi^{-1} \to 0$ and
$$ h(y) \sim \frac{\pi}{4^{\nu}\Gamma(\nu)\Gamma(\nu+1)} y^{\nu} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{2\nu} g_{\nu}'(x)}{g_{\nu}(x)^2} \, \mathrm{d}x
\quad \text{as } y \to 0^+. $$
The corresponding asymptotic behavior of $f(y)$ follows from
$$ f(y) = \frac{2^{\nu}}{\pi \Gamma(\nu - 1)} \frac{h(y)}{y}. $$

Hi @SangchulLee, yes that is more or less what I had tried and numerically was working decently and  I was finding that adjusting $\omega$ was giving better convergence. Still would like to say something about the analytic behaviour of this function . I think that one should be able to estimate the beaviour near $y\sim 0$ and $y\sim 1$ using a saddle point type argument...

@gdvdv, You could have also shared your approach so others don't have to spend time on what you already know... Anyway, I added my own take of the asymptotic behavior of $f(y)$ as $y \to 0^+$ or $y \to 1^-$, modulo some ansatz.
